# SyntaxError while defining and calling a function

Tags: python, syntax-error

I have been asked to:

> Write a function called `start_codon` which accepts a DNA sequence as its argument and returns the first codon as a string.

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def start_codon(dna):

    codon1 = dna[0:3]
    codonstring = codon1.split(",");
    return codonstring

print (start_codon(“ATGGAACCAACGTCAGTGACTTCGTCAG”))
```

However, when I press enter to try and call the function, I get a syntax error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
    print (start_codon(“ATGGAACCAACGTCAGTGACTTCGTCAG”))
                       ^
```

Comment: The sample you posted looks like it has "curly quotes".  You need plain "straight" double or single quote characters.

Comment: Note also that your `codonstring` will be a list, despite its name.

Comment: @jonrsharpe How would I make it into a comma separated list? I thought that's what the second argument was

Comment: That's what you're already doing, but the spec says it should return a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [string literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-stringliteral) is malformed.  You must use either quotation marks `"..."` or apostrophes `'...'`:

```
print (start_codon("ATGGAACCAACGTCAGTGACTTCGTCAG"))
# or
print (start_codon('ATGGAACCAACGTCAGTGACTTCGTCAG'))
```

`“` and `”` are special characters that are not recognized by Python.